# What is the difference between solutions to 2nd order homogeneous ODE?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, complex-numbers, differential-equations, vibrations, linear-systems

I’m studying Vibrations, and we have two forms to the 2nd order homogeneous ODE:
$$mx ̈+kx ̇=0$$
$$x(t)=C_1 e^{iw_n t}+C_2 e^{-iw_n t}$$
and
$$x(t)=A\cos(w_n t)+B\sin(w_n t)$$
Even though I can use either solution for a given problem (for simple problems), what is the difference between solutions to 2nd order homogeneous ODE? When to use one over the other? Are there situations when one form is more useful than the other?

Comment: Actually these two solutions are equal they are not different

Comment: @Sourabh, typically $A$ and $B$ are real and then the second solution is real but the first solution is real only if $C_2 = C^*_1$ so there is that difference.

Comment: @HalHollis Just use relation between exopnential and sine and cosine and then you will see that 1st solution as well as second function are not real because $B$ is not real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the difference between solutions to 2nd order homogeneous ODE?

The second form is a special case of the first form when $C_2 = C^*_1$ in which case $x(t)$ is a real valued function of time (I'm assuming here that both $A$ and $B$ are real)

Using [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), the first form can be written as

$$\left(C_1 + C_2\right)\cos(\omega_n t) + i\left(C_1 - C_2\right)\sin(\omega_n t)$$

where, in general, $C_1$ and $C_2$ are complex numbers.  Now, if $C_2 = C^*_1$ then this is just

$$2\Re\{C_2\}\cos(\omega_n t) + 2\Im\{C_2\}\sin(\omega_n t)$$

and so

$$A = 2\Re\{C_2\}$$

$$B = 2\Im\{C_2\}$$

> When to use one over the other?

For $x(t)$ real, the second form is explicitly real.

Comment: Note also for the real and imaginary parts of the complex exponential solution, $\Re\{ x(t)\}$ and $\Im\{ x(t)\}$, are themselves two independent solutions, and so are the two *real* solutions $\Re\{ x(t)\}$ and $i \Im\{x(t)\}$. This is nice, because sometimes you can do some math with the complex solution, and extract two independent real solutions at the end - which is less work than *starting* with two independent real solutions and doing the math on both of them separately. This is even nicer if the RHS of the diff.eq. is not zero, but a harmonic forcing term like $\Re\{Fe^{iwt}\}$.

Comment: @alephzero, isn't $\Im\{x(t)\}$ real?  Or, put another way, for $x(t)$ complex, $$x(t) = \Re\{x(t)\} + i\Im\{x(t)\}$$

Comment: Thank you for cementing the idea that two solutions are the same. But I also would like to know if one is more advantageous over the over with respect to the study of Mechanical Vibrations.

Comment: what does asterisk mean beside $C_1$ ?

Comment: @JekDenys, advantageous in what way?  If $x(t)$ is a displacement, then you can see that the second form of the solution can be written in terms of the initial conditions (initial displacement $x_0$ and initial velocity $v_0$) as so:  $$x(t) = x_0\cos(\omega t) + \frac{v_0}{\omega}\sin(\omega t)$$  The asterisk means [complex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate)

Comment: @HalHollis, well, I don't know, that's precisely my question. I'm only half-way through the course and don't know if there is an advantage of using one form over the other in some situations that I haven't learned about yet. So I'm looking for clarifications about this from someone who went through the study of Mechanical Vibrations, and can tell me that yeah, this form is best used here. Or, nop, it won't matter in any situation of Mech Vib.

Comment: @HalHollis, so A and B are real values. Yes. I should have mentioned this.
Can you add to your answer that the second form of the solutions (with A & B) is giving explicitly Real values please?

Comment: @JekDenys, I think I've already stated that in the final sentence of my answer.  Still, I will update my answer to make that point clear.

Answer (score 1):

No difference. Write $\sin(x)=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$ and $\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})$

$$A\cos(wt)+B\sin(wt)=\frac{1}{2}A(e^{iwt}+e^{-iwt})+\frac{1}{2i}B(e^{iwt}-e^{-iwt})=\frac{1}{2}(A-iB)e^{iwt}+\frac{1}{2}(A+iB)e^{-iwt}$$

the two solutions are the same for $$C_1=\frac{1}{2}(A-iB)\\C_2=\frac{1}{2}(A+iB) $$

Comment: Of course, I'm sorry, I corrected the answer (I thought something was off..)

Comment: Thank you for cementing the idea that two solutions are the same. But I also would like to know if one is more advantageous over the over with respect to the study of Mechanical Vibrations.

Comment: It's just a matter of convenience. Often it is nicer to work with exponentials instead of trigonometric functions because exponential identities are easier to remember and quicker to apply, other times you want it to be explicit that the solution is real.

Comment: Ah! I see. That helps. If only your comment could be added to @Hal Hollis 's answer!

Comment: Yes his answer is more precise in stating that in general one is a special case of the other, I suggest you accept @Hal Hollis' answer